# Getting null value in parameter when importing data from XML to SQL Server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, sqlxml

I have xml document that I need to transfer to SQL Server table. All is working fine but not sure why I am getting null values for parameter; in my case is instancekey

### XML Document

```
<response>
- <item instancekey="0">
  <title>First Steps in Photo Shop and Digital Imaging</title> 
  <field_unit_instance_code>VE1EC37</field_unit_instance_code> 
  <field_market_area_description>Adults</field_market_area_description> 
  <field_ssa_description>Creative Arts, Design and Crafts</field_ssa_description> 
  <field_school_owning>Creative Arts and Digital Industries</field_school_owning> 
  <field_course_overview /> 
  <field_entry_requirements /> 
  <field_teaching_methods /> 
  <field_modules_and_assessment /> 
  <field_career_options_and_progres /> 
  <field_equipment_needed_and_costs /> 
  <field_work_placement_field_trips /> 
</item>
- <item instancekey="1">
 <title>Print Techniques</title> 
 <field_unit_instance_code>VE1EC36</field_unit_instance_code> 
 <field_market_area_description>Adults</field_market_area_description> 
 <field_ssa_description>Creative Arts, Design and Crafts</field_ssa_description> 
 <field_school_owning>Creative Arts and Digital Industries</field_school_owning> 
 <field_course_overview /> 
 <field_entry_requirements /> 
 <field_teaching_methods /> 
 <field_modules_and_assessment /> 
 <field_career_options_and_progres /> 
 <field_equipment_needed_and_costs /> 
 <field_work_placement_field_trips /> 
</item>
//remain records
```

### SQL Server Script to import XML data

```
 DECLARE @x xml
 SELECT @x=P
 FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'H:\My Work\instance_marketing.xml', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS  COURSE_INSTANCE(P)

DECLARE @hdoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@hdoc,'/response/item', 1)
WITH(
    instancekey int
   )    

 SELECT *
  FROM OPENXML(@hdoc,'/response/item', 2)
  WITH(
     CourseInstanceKey int '../../@instancekey',  //Getting Null Value here
     title varchar(300),
     field_unit_instance_code varchar(300),
     field_market_area_description varchar(3000),
     field_ssa_description varchar(3000),
     field_school_owning varchar(3000),
     field_course_overview varchar(3000), 
     field_entry_requirements varchar(3000),
     field_teaching_methods varchar(3000),
     field_modules_and_assessment varchar(3000),
     field_career_options_and_progres varchar(3000),
     field_equipment_needed_and_costs varchar(3000),
     field_work_placement_field_trips varchar(3000)
    )   

       EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

Comment: why the `../../` in the xpath for the `@instancekey`?

Comment: I have just tried with one like ../ and still getting null value

Comment: my fault find the answer

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `FROM OPENXML` with the surrounding calls to `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` is outdated and should be replaced by the modern XML methods `.nodes()`, `.query()`, `.value()` and `.modify()`.

Your query is faster, cleaner and better to maintain if you put it like this:

```
DECLARE @x XML=
N'<response>
  <item instancekey="0">
    <title>First Steps in Photo Shop and Digital Imaging</title>
    <field_unit_instance_code>VE1EC37</field_unit_instance_code>
    <field_market_area_description>Adults</field_market_area_description>
    <field_ssa_description>Creative Arts, Design and Crafts</field_ssa_description>
    <field_school_owning>Creative Arts and Digital Industries</field_school_owning>
    <field_course_overview />
    <field_entry_requirements />
    <field_teaching_methods />
    <field_modules_and_assessment />
    <field_career_options_and_progres />
    <field_equipment_needed_and_costs />
    <field_work_placement_field_trips />
  </item>
  <item instancekey="1">
    <title>Print Techniques</title>
    <field_unit_instance_code>VE1EC36</field_unit_instance_code>
    <field_market_area_description>Adults</field_market_area_description>
    <field_ssa_description>Creative Arts, Design and Crafts</field_ssa_description>
    <field_school_owning>Creative Arts and Digital Industries</field_school_owning>
    <field_course_overview />
    <field_entry_requirements />
    <field_teaching_methods />
    <field_modules_and_assessment />
    <field_career_options_and_progres />
    <field_equipment_needed_and_costs />
    <field_work_placement_field_trips />
  </item>
</response>';
```

--The query

```
SELECT i.value('@instancekey','int') AS title
      ,i.value('title[1]','nvarchar(300)') AS title
      ,i.value('field_unit_instance_code[1]','nvarchar(300)') AS field_unit_instance_code
      ,i.value('field_market_area_description[1]','nvarchar(3000)') AS field_market_area_description
      ,i.value('field_ssa_description[1]','nvarchar(3000)') AS field_ssa_description
      ,i.value('field_school_owning[1]','nvarchar(3000)') AS field_school_owning
      ,i.value('field_course_overview[1]','nvarchar(3000)') AS field_course_overview
      ,i.value('field_entry_requirements[1]','nvarchar(3000)') AS field_entry_requirements
      ,i.value('field_teaching_methods[1]','nvarchar(3000)') AS field_teaching_methods
      ,i.value('field_modules_and_assessment[1]','nvarchar(3000)') AS field_modules_and_assessment
      ,i.value('field_career_options_and_progres[1]','nvarchar(3000)') AS field_career_options_and_progres
      ,i.value('field_equipment_needed_and_costs[1]','nvarchar(3000)') AS field_equipment_needed_and_costs
      ,i.value('field_work_placement_field_trips[1]','nvarchar(3000)') AS field_work_placement_field_trips
FROM @x.nodes('response/item') AS a(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@hdoc,'/response/item', 2)
WITH(
 CourseInstanceKey int '@instancekey',
 title varchar(300),
 field_unit_instance_code varchar(300),
```